python 3 using ffmpeg in a subprocess getting stderr decoding error
I am running ffmpeg as a  subprocess  and using the stderr to get various bits of data like the subtitles stream Id's. It works fine for most videos, but one with japanese subtitles  results in an error:
'charmap' codec can't decode byte in position xxx : character maps to 
Much googling suggests the problem is  that the japanese requires unicode, whereas English does not. Solutions offered refer to problems with files, and I cannot find a way of doing the same with  the stderr. Relevent Code is below:
command = [ffmpeg,"-y","-i",fileSelected,"-acodec","pcm_s16le",
                  "-vn","-t","3", "-f",            "null","-"]
print(command)   
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stderr=PIPE,Jstdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True,startupinfo=startupinfo)
  
stream = ""    
for line in proc.stderr:
    try:
        print("line",line)
    except exception as error:
        print("print",error)
        line = line[:-1]
        if "Stream #" in line:
            estream = line.split("#",1)[1]
            estream =estream.split(" (",1)[0]
            print("estream",estream)
            stream = stream + estream +"\n"  #.split("(",1)[0] 
            stream = stream + estream +"\n"


you can stipulate encoding as:
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, startupinfo=startupinfo, encoding='utf-8')

It may also be a good idea for you to not use universal_newlines as that can sometimes cause issues with streams.
I would also move your stream extraction into your try: except: block in order to provide for sane crashes.
Hope this helps

I should have seen that!, thanks it has sorted the problem.  including universal_newlines hasn't caused me any problems as yet, but will bear it in mind
